# Robolectric tests throw RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

I've wrote simple hello-world with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) test.

I've added to build.gradle proper dependencies:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
```

Here's my simple `CartModel.java` to test:

```
public class CartModel {
    public float totalAmount;
    public int products;

    public void addToCart(float productPrice) {
        products++;
        totalAmount += productPrice;
    }
}
```

`CartModelTest.java`

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21)
public class CartModelTest {

    @Test
    public void addToCart() throws Exception {
        CartModel cartModel = new CartModel();
        assertEquals(0, cartModel.totalAmount, 0);
        assertEquals(0, cartModel.products);
        cartModel.addToCart(10.2f);
        assertEquals(10.2f, cartModel.totalAmount, 0);
        assertEquals(1, cartModel.products);
    }
}
```

Once I click to Run the test:
[image]

**I get a test failure with this exception:**

> **java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find a class for package:  and class name: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication**
>       at org.robolectric.DefaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(DefaultTestLifecycle.java:61)
>       at org.robolectric.DefaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(DefaultTestLifecycle.java:15)
>       at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:102)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find a class for package: klogi.com.dummyapp and class name: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
>       at org.robolectric.internal.ClassNameResolver.resolve(ClassNameResolver.java:25)
>       at org.robolectric.DefaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(DefaultTestLifecycle.java:59)
>       ... 30 more

I run Android Studio 2.0 Preview 3b.

**The question is:** how to avoid the failure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's pretty bizarre, but all I had to do - is to **disable instant run** (Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run - uncheck) in Android Studio.

[image]

Now all tests are passing.

Comment: Probably you could also add another testCompile for build tools dependency that contains that class

Comment: @eugenmartynov , Thank you for your comment! correct me if I'm wrong, will this suggestion to keep instant build for the app and disable instant build for unit tests?

Comment: If you manage it to work then you can keep instant run. But it will be not easy most probably

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem.
Worth notifying the dev team about it so they can fix it in the next releases.

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov great answer to your own question! Thanks, it helped me a lot!